# Hiding Rows using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have tried to follow a previous question regarding hiding rows based on a cells value (E19)

```
Sub HideIR()

If Range("$E$19").Value = "2" Then
        Rows("20:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("$E$19").Value = "1" Then
        Rows("20:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("$E$19").Value = "2" Then
        Rows("20:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("$E$19").Value = "1" Then
        Rows("20:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If
End Sub
```

It will hide the cells, however it does not refresh when I change values without running the macro again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your code in [`Sub Worksheet_change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) of your sheet's code module (not just a general module), so it'll run after you change any value in your sheet.

Comment: I see you have edited the OP's question. The question itself now provides what you suggest. Is this a mistake on your end, maybe?

Comment: @LPChip: I've only formatted code. I didn't even realized second sub is already there:(.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as such. :) Maybe because that sub is private, that it doesn't work.